# How to get a windows control panel in x64 system?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, controlpanel

I use Shell to get control panel

Code :

```
var
  psfDeskTop: IShellFolder;
  psfControl: IShellFolder;

  pidControl: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidChild: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidAbsolute: PItemIdList;

  pEnumList: IEnumIDList;
  celtFetched: ULONG;

  FileInfo: SHFILEINFOW;

begin

  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop));
  OleCheck(SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_CONTROLS, pidControl));
  OleCheck(psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidControl, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfControl));
  OleCheck(psfControl.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN or SHCONTF_FOLDERS, pEnumList));

  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
  begin

    pidAbsolute := ILCombine(pidControl, pidChild);
    SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(pidAbsolute), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL
      or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME);
    Memo1.Add(FileInfo.szDisplayName);

  end;

end;
```

it only can get control panels in 32-bit like :  BDE Administrator (32 bit) , Flash Player (32 bit), 
and my operating system is x64 , I wonder how to get all (32bit & 64bit) control panel ?

Comment: Your 32 bit process is running in an emulator, WOW64. Use 64 bit process.

Comment: In other words, if you have Delphi XE2 or XE3, change your Delphi target from Win32 to Win64. If you don't have it yet, get a modern 32+64 bit delphi version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm going to post what you say as an answer, but I came to your comment, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @jachguate can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: @ONion Using XE2 or XE3, compile your app targeting 64 bit rather than 32 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan heheh, too late for me! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your code as a 64 bit process to see the 64 bit control panel items. That needs XE2 or later. When I try your code in a 64 bit process the output is as follows:

```
NVIDIA nView Desktop Manager
Power Options
Notification Area Icons
Taskbar and Start Menu
Credential Manager
Default Programs
RemoteApp and Desktop Connections
Windows Live Language Setting
Windows Update
Desktop Gadgets
Windows Firewall
Phone and Modem
Speech Recognition
User Accounts
Region and Language
HomeGroup
Mouse
Folder Options
Keyboard
Device Manager
Windows CardSpace
Performance Information and Tools
Programs and Features
Indexing Options
Network and Sharing Center
AutoPlay
Sync Center
Recovery
Internet Options
Devices and Printers
Color Management
Backup and Restore
System
Action Center
Fonts
Windows Anytime Upgrade
Display
Troubleshooting
Getting Started
Administrative Tools
Ease of Access Center
Windows Defender
Date and Time
Location and Other Sensors
Personalization
Sound
Java (32-bit)
DirectX
Realtek HD Audio Manager
BDE Administrator (32-bit)
Advansys Formativ (32-bit)
Mail (32-bit)
Microsoft Mail Postoffice (32-bit)
Flash Player (32-bit)
NVIDIA Control Panel
```

In a 32 bit process the output is:

```
Java
BDE Administrator
Advansys Formativ
Mail
Microsoft Mail Postoffice
Flash Player
```

Note that the 64 bit process enumerates the 32 bit items as well as the 64 bit items.